# Group DataTable by Column1 & Concat Column2

Tags: linq, datatable, concatenation, grouping

I have DataTable with 2 column:

```
    Column1                                 Column2
1039-F42F-87BF-723B-529E-6B76-DD92-5ED3     1
1039-F42F-87BF-723B-529E-6B76-DD92-5ED3     2
1039-F42F-87BF-723B-529E-6B76-DD92-5ED3     3
41F7-F8CB-F7A1-9AC5-6C72-3A08-361F-8803     1
9714-96BD-F411-5868-4DD1-A08D-C5B1-B872     1
9714-96BD-F411-5868-4DD1-A08D-C5B1-B872     2
9E0E-BC55-374B-5B57-FC04-C2D6-C621-95F7     1
9E0E-BC55-374B-5B57-FC04-C2D6-C621-95F7     2
9E0E-BC55-374B-5B57-FC04-C2D6-C621-95F7     3
9E0E-BC55-374B-5B57-FC04-C2D6-C621-95F7     4
```

How can I get another DataTable by Grouping Column1 and concat Column2 values?
LINQ would be a perfect choice, but how to do this?
Result must be DataTable below:

```
    Column1                                 Column2
1039-F42F-87BF-723B-529E-6B76-DD92-5ED3     1,2,3
41F7-F8CB-F7A1-9AC5-6C72-3A08-361F-8803     1
9714-96BD-F411-5868-4DD1-A08D-C5B1-B872     1,2
9E0E-BC55-374B-5B57-FC04-C2D6-C621-95F7     1,2,3,4
```